# Show a component only once in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi i have this `Reactjs` component ,in this component I am displaying the messages between two users, And I need to show a `typing indicator` when the the other user is typing .I am able to show the messages between two users, but the problem is I need to show `typing indicator` below all the messages  for that I am using this condition `{chatWith.isTyping === "composing" ? "Typing" : ""}`.This condition is working but in the `UI` am not able to show, in the UI if there are 5 messages its showing five times Typing.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function ShowMessages({ idx, item }) {
  const chatWith = useSelector((state) => state.user.chatWith);

  return (
    <>
      <li className={item.direction === "send" ? "replies" : "sent"} key={idx}>
        <div className="media-body">
          <h5>{item.body}</h5>
        </div>
      </li>
      <div className="sent">
        {chatWith.isTyping === "composing" ? "Typing" : ""}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default ShowMessages;
```

Comment: That is because you are using it in every message component. If you want to show it once please consider managing its state in its parent div or component

Comment: Sagar :Can you please update your answer

Comment: You mean about the state ? @Zeeshan  I was just suggesting. If you use redux even then you should render the `Typing` component in parent div. It would be better if you share ur code on how you render the messages